# Find all files in all subdirectories

Tags: ubuntu, find

I have that kind of paths on Ubuntu:

```
my_public/system/backgrounds/123/original/2.jpg

my_public/system/backgrounds/1233/original/1.jpg

my_public/system/backgrounds/99993/original/1.jpg
```

so as You can see, there are many `subfolders` in `backgrounds` folder, and every backgrounds subfolder  have one `original` subfolder with file: `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` or `3.jpg`

What I need to do is to delete all files in all `original` subfolders.

I'm not to good in this and do not find any solution ... I want something like this:

```
find /backgrounds/*/original/*.jpg -delete
```

Comment: Did you read the `find` documentation? You can use the `-exec` option. See the manual for details.

Comment: yes but I do not see any examples for me

Comment: See [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) manual page. There is a `-delete` command. Read through, it explains.